# AspectJ project as a jar to another project

Tags: aop, aspectj

I have 2 projects. 
Project A - This is an aspectJ project. For example: It prints the method name and time taken, in console after execution of each method.
Project B - It is a sample web project.

I want to add Project A as a Jar to Project B. So whenever I run Project B, it should display what are the method names and time taken.

Since I am new to AspectJ , could someone explain how to do this. Please explain with some sample projects. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- Use A as an aspect library when compiling B with the AspectJ compiler *Ajc*. This can be done from command line, from IDE with the right project configuration or, most conveniently, via AspectJ Maven plugin.
- Use A as an aspect library and B as a weave dependency in a post-processing step with *Ajc*. As before, this can be done from command line, from IDE with the right project configuration or, most conveniently, via AspectJ Maven plugin.
- Use load-time weaving (LTW) via `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` command-line switch when starting your Java application containing B and put A on the classpath as an aspect library.

For more information please use your favourite web search engine, specifying search terms like "aspectj ltw", "aspectj maven plugin", "aspectj ajc" or similar.

P.S.: Why should anyone provide one or multiple full sample projects if you are too lazy to provide a single line of code?

Comment: Thanks..I didn't add code because I had not started working on it, so I didn't had code.